# sed regex on text with closing bracket

Tags: regex, sed

I have a quite complicated problem, but here I try to show a simplified one.
I have many strings in a text like these:

```
' key=value '
'[key2=value2]'
' key3=value3]'
'[key4=value3,'
```

My goal is to transform these strings in a format like this: "key" -> "value" with keeping the terminating characters. For example:
' key3=value3]'  ->  ' "key3" -> "value3"]'
Unfortunately many chars can be terminating, but specifying the terminating chars are still viable than trying to define the non-terminating.

This is how far I got:

```
$ echo ' key1=value1' | sed -E -e 's/([^\t []+)=(.+)(\[|$|[ \t])/"\1" -> "\2"\3/g'
```

I have no problem with my solution except the closing bracket (]) always treated as a non-terminal character and takes precedence over the others, like this:

```
 ' key1=value1] '   ->   '"key1" -> "value1]"'   instead of this: '"key1" -> "value1"]'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd break it up into smaller steps instead of trying to build one huge expression:

```
sed -E '
    s/^([^=]+)=(.*)/"\1" -> "\2"/
    s/^"([[:blank:][])/\1"/
    s/([][:blank:]])"$/"\1/
' file
```

```
 "key" -> "value" 
["key2" -> "value2"]
 "key3" -> "value3"]
["key4" -> "value3,"
```